# Java Class Nesting by use of Reference Class in terms of Convention

Tags: java, performance, conventions

I was thinking about the resource that classes take up, vs trying to make my code look 'good' (to me.) I was wondering if the following would be wrong by convention (as I know it is 100% negligible in terms of runtime/compilation.)

```
import x;
import y;
import z;

public class app {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         x var1 = new x();
         y var2 = new y();
         z var3 = new z();
         doSomething(x,y,z)
    }
}
```

versus

```
import abc;
public class app {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         abc ref = new abc()
         ref.var1 = new x();
         ref.var2 = new y();
         ref.var3 = new z();
         doSomething(ref);
    }
} 
--------
import x;
import y;
import z;
public class abc {
    x var1;
    y var2;
    z var3;

    public abc() {
    … 
    //you get the point
    }
}
```

Collecting all of the classes and putting them into one 'Reference' class to pass around -could- make code easier to read and code in situations where a ton of stuff needs to be passed to a ton of different methods, but I haven't seen anybody do it. Is there some hidden secret in doing this that will cause the heat-death of the universe? Or is it just against convention?

Comment: I think most of the time, you don't really need *all* that information, so you should really only be passing around information that is necessary. Don't over share. If you pass around things that you don't need you might accidentally add dependencies which makes things less maintainable.

Comment: It depends whether it makes sense if these data goes into a container. For example, if I have an `age` field, it would make sense for it to go into a `Person` class, unless you are *only* interested to look at a collection/array of age values.

Comment: These more or less answer the question. Thanks.